# Map of strings can't handle more than varchar(255)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Once total length of Map String(s) is greater than 255, JPA fails committing transaction. I'm using JPA 2.0 with Play 2 Framework.

```
@ElementCollection
private Map<EmailNotificationType, String> mailContents = new HashMap<>();
```

I tried

> @Column(length = 2048)
>
> @Lob
>
> @MapKeyColumn(length = 2048)

I would like to persist as much as  it's possible since its size is dynamic.

Comment: Do you get an exception?

Comment: `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: value too long for type character varying(255)` which ends with a [RollbackException]

Comment: Your DB column has a maximum length of 255 characters - how did you define the table structure?

Comment: Ok, I never had to define my table structure since JPA does it for me using javax annotations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are using `varchar(255)`. Use a `text` column instead of `varchar(255)`.

In PostgreSQL always use text (unless of course there is a real length constraint).

Answer (score 11):

For people who landet here by google:

Answer is:

@Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")

or

@Column(columnDefinition = "LONGTEXT")

The old DB content of the DB must be deleted before, like create-drop. Update is not working.

Comment: I would expect this to be the correct answer, however, when I tried it, *(I first dropped the whole DB and recompiled, recreated DB, I got again `character varying(255)` ...???